# Is logging in Cloud Functions (Node.JS) asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using simple runtime logging a lot in my Node.JS Cloud Functions

```
console.log('I am a log entry!');
```

Is console.log in Cloud Functions asynchronous in its nature?

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to explain what you're observing the raises the question. I would have no reason to assume that logging is asynchronous unless I saw something that indicated that might be the case. It would help also if you showed the entire program that doesn't work the way you expect - something else might be going wrong besides logging.

Comment: No it is not a asynchronous

Comment: In the original implementation of node.js it was asynchronous. However `console.log()` was made synchronous some time in version 4 (2015). The reason for it was to avoid losing logs when a node process crashes. Making it synchronous ensures that all the text of the log gets printed before the process dies.

Comment: Note however that 3rd party logging libraries like Winston or syslog may still be asynchronous. Some may be configured to be sync or async. The built-in `console.log()` is synchronous.

Comment: @slebetman , could you please post it as an answer so it could also help the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @slebetman stated, In the original implementation of node.js it was asynchronous. However, `console.log()` was made synchronous some time in version 4 (2015). The reason for it was to avoid losing logs when a node process crashes. Making it synchronous ensures that all the text of the log gets printed before the process dies.

**Note:** However, 3rd party logging libraries like [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) or [syslog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-syslog) may still be asynchronous. Some may be configured to be sync or async. The built-in `console.log()` is synchronous.